# how to create tree using # define

Tags: c

I want to create a tree. I saw the following code

```
#define NODEALLOC(struct treenode*)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode))

    struct treenode{

          int data;
         struct treenode * left;
         strruct treenode *right;

   }
typedef struct treenode *treeptr;
treeptr root;

treeptr create(int d)
 {

treeptr root;
root =NODEALLOC;
root->data=d;
root->left=null;
root->right=null;
 return root;
}
```

I am not understanding the `#define` statement.can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's wrong, it needs a space between the `NODEALLOC` and the `(`

Second, it's evil. There *are* good uses for macros; this is not one of them.

Here's how it works:

It's a simple string substitution, so when you see `root=NODEALLOC;` it becomes `root=(struct treenode*)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode))`

`malloc(n)` allocates n bytes of memory, `sizeof` tells malloc how big `n` needs to be, and `(struct treenode*)` casts malloc's returned `void*` into the correct type.

Comment: It's even more evil than that because it casts the result of malloc.

Comment: You *have* to hast the result of malloc. It would be evil if it cast the result of `new`.

Comment: @spraff: In C, casting the return value of malloc is not common practice.

Comment: That's because you normally write `foo * x = malloc (sizeof *foo)` but if you *are* going to have a *dedicated* `alloc_foo` function/macro then it *should* cast the result to stop you writing `bar * x = alloc_foo()` -- that's the one thing about this `NODEALLOC`

Comment: @spraff: this is C, not C++ - you really should not cast the result of malloc in C (unfortunately you have no choice in C++).

Comment: Why not? I see only advantages to narrowing the type ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use that. Use a function if you don't wan't to write the `malloc` more than once. Using macros like this is something you should better avoid (it's legal, but not considered a good practice).

If you don't know what macros are in the first place, [read](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Replace NODEALLOC in code with its definition. In your case:

```
treeptr create(int d)
{
  treeptr root;
  root = (struct treenode*)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode)); // was NODEALLOC;
  root->data=d;
  root->left=null;
  root->right=null;
  return root;
}
```

Thus, this is a simple allocation.

However, using a macro only for this is not really helpful, it can even confuse readers of your code. Usually, a macro should do something useful.